# Angular custom input mask

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to apply custom mask to the input:

Here are the different formats which I receive from the back-end and they should be applied:

```
#####
@@ #####
LT #####
971 ###
####-####
```

`#` - numbers
`@` - letters

So, if the mask is `971 ###`, the input should allow user to enter 3 numbers and 971 will be a prefix. How can this be achieved? It seems like `ngx-mask` and similar libraries doesn't provide such features.

Comment: are you using material angular library ?

Comment: @abhaytripathi No, ngx-mask